# How to convert a regression interaction plot to ggplot?

Tags: r, ggplot2, regression, interaction

Can someone please show me how to plot with ggplot the interaction effect below (code generated by using [this](http://www.quantpsy.org/interact/hlm2.htm) tool):

```
xx <- c(40,65)   
yy <- c(26.77,37.15)
x <- c(40,65)   #  <-- x-coords for lines
y1 <- c(28.5,37.15)
y2 <- c(30.345,35.895)
y3 <- c(32.19,34.64)
plot(xx,yy,type='n',font=2,font.lab=2,xlab='x1',ylab='Y',main='2-Way Interaction Plot')
lines(x,y1,lwd=3,lty=1,col=1)
lines(x,y2,lwd=3,lty=5,col=2)
lines(x,y3,lwd=3,lty=6,col=3)
points(x,y1,col=1,pch=16)
points(x,y2,col=1,pch=16)
points(x,y3,col=1,pch=16)                                                      
legend(leg[1],leg[2],legend=c('W1(1)','W1(2)','W1(3)'),lwd=c(3,3,3),lty=c(1,5,6),col=c(1,2,3))
```

y1, y2, y3 are the points/conditional slope values for the moderator.

Comment: Welcome to Cross Validated! But this question is about programming & would be better at Stack Overflow.

Comment: I hope [this](http://www.cookbook-r.com/Graphs/Bar_and_line_graphs_%28ggplot2%29/#with-x-axis-treated-as-continuous) and [this](http://docs.ggplot2.org/current/stat_summary.html) example will get you started.

Comment: Check your syntax, please. And what are `leg[1]` and `leg[2]`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need a dataframe in long format:

```
dfrm <- data.frame(x=rep(x,3), y=c(y1,y2,y3), 
                   group=rep(c("y1","y2","y3") ,each=2) ) 
ggplot(data=dfrm, aes(x=x,y=y,group=group) ) +
                      geom_point()+geom_line(aes(col=group))
```

(The legend appears automagically.) There are also `xlim` and `ylim` functions if you wanted to enforce the 'xx' and yy limits that you applied to the blank plot framework in your base graphics template.

[image]

Comment: thanks @DWin. In case someone else is novice in R like me and is trying to replicate: group is the moderator "w"-variable  and  y1,y2,y3 above are conditional values at w(values). The code for the data frame AND ggplot is:
'group= c("w(1)", "w(1)", "w(2)", "w(2)", "w(3)", "w(3)")
    x= c(40, 65, 40, 65, 40, 65)
    y= c(28.5, 37.15, 30.345, 35.895, 32.19, 34.64)
    mydata<- data.frame (x, y, group)
    ggplot(data=mydata, aes(x=x,y=y,group=group) ) +
                      geom_point()+geom_line(aes(col=group))'